# Can I keep a copy of a table of one database in another database in a microservice architecture?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, domain-driven-design

I am currently new to microservice architecture so thanks in advance.

I have two different services a User Service and a Footballer Service each having their individual databases.(User database and Footballer database).
The Footballer service has a database with a single table storing footballer informations.
The User service has a database which stores User details along with other user related data.

Now a User can add footballers to their team by querying the Footballer service and I need to store them somewhere in order to be displayed later.
Currently I'm storing the footballers for each user in a table in the User database whereby I make a call to the Footballer service to give me the details of a specific footballer by ID and save them in the USer database by mapping against the USer ID.

So is this a good idea to do that and by any chance does it mean im replicating data between two services
and if it is than what other ways can i achieve the same functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I'm storing the footballers for each user in a table in the User database whereby I make a call to the Footballer service to give me the details of a specific footballer by ID and save them in the USer database by mapping against the USer ID.

"Caching" is a fairly common pattern.  From the perspective of the User microservice, the data from Footballer is just another input which you might save or not.  If you are caching, you'll usually want to have some sort of timestamp/version on the cached data.

Caching *identifiers* is pretty normal - we often need some kind of [correlation identifier](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CorrelationIdentifier.html) to connect data in two different places.

If you find yourself using Footballer data in your User domain logic (that is to say, the way that User changes depends on the Footballer data available)... that's more suspicious, and may indicate that your boundaries are incorrectly drawn / some of your capabilities are in the wrong place.

If you are expecting the User Service to be autonomous - that is to say, to be able to continue serving its purpose even when Footballer is out of service, then your code needs to be able to work from cached copies of the data from Footballer and/or be able to suspend some parts of its work until fresh copies of that data are available.

Answer (score 0):

People usually follow DDD (Domain driven design) in case of micro-services  :
So here in your case there are two domains i.e. 2 services :

1. Users
2. Footballers

So, user service should only do user specific tasks, it should not be concerned about footballer's data.

Hence, according to DDD, the footballers that are linked to the user should be stored in football service.

Replicating the ID wouldn't be considered replication in case of microservices architecture.

Comment: Actually I want to make the footballers reusable.Say suppose User A adds 11 footballers to their team another User B can also add some of those footballers to his team also.The footballers that are to be to displayed should be very much user speciific. According to your suggestion what I can do is store the footballers id in the Users tables. That would be architecturally correct right?

Comment: Footballers is a separate table or is it a type of user?

Comment: Footballer service has a different database containing only footballer information. Then there's the User service which has a addFootballer function which takes in the id of the particular footballer to be added which in turns makes a call to the Footballer service to get the particular footballer and store that particular footballer for that particular user.

Comment: The way I'm currently doing is I have created a separate table to store the footballer id that the User adds in the User database. So that when  displaying the list of footballers for a specific user it doesn't have to make another call to the footballer service. Is this somehow data replication or is it a good practice?

Comment: No, i wouldn't consider it as a good practice. Good practice would be to have a separate table for relation between user and footballer in FOOTBALLER service i.e. footballer database. So, whenever you need footballer data, then you can make api call from user service to footballer service. In case, you just need the footballer data, then you can directly call the footballer service.

Comment: Awesome,got the idea.Thanks!!